# Unable to combine multiple audio files into one in a keyboard extension running on an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avmutablecomposition

The keyboard extension I built uses audio files to play audio feedback when keys are pressed. At some point, the user has an ability to combine multiple audio files into a single audio file. Combining multiple audio files works in simulator but does not work on the device.

```
func createSound(myNotes: [String], outputFile: String) {
    // CMTime struct represents a length of time that is stored as rational number
    var startTime: CMTime = kCMTimeZero
    // AVMutableComposition creates new composition
    let composition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    // AVMutableCompositionTrack - A mutable track in composition that you use to insert, remove, and scale track segments
    if let compositionAudioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {

      for url in allFilesForCharacters() {
        let avAsset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let timeRange: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
        let audioTrack: AVAssetTrack = avAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]
        try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: startTime)
        startTime = CMTimeAdd(startTime, timeRange.duration)
      }
    }

    let exportPath: String = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].path+"/"+outputFile+".m4a"

    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: exportPath)

    if let export: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) {

      export.outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)
      export.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a

      export.exportAsynchronously {
        if export.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
          NSLog("All done");
          if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: export.outputURL!) {
            let board = UIPasteboard.general
            board.setData(data, forPasteboardType: kUTTypeMPEG4Audio as String)
          }
        }
        else {
          print(export.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I was getting "AudioQueueNew returned server error" and  "Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioSession"

Comment: But I was able to solve the issue earlier since I didn't realize the app had an allow full access switch in the apps settings bundle in its keyboard settings

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to solve the issue after realizing that the app had an allow full access switch in its settings. After turning it on, everything worked as expected. The app couldn't carry out its functionality because the device was blocking it from accessing the devices data.